# How to put the url inside the button?

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, geturl

How to put the url inside the button?
I'm not able to pull the json url for this code, what is wrong?

```
// listar();
        
function listar() {
  var url_string = window.location.href;
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var ponto = url.searchParams.get("jsonProdutos");
  console.log(ponto)
  var html = '';
  var quantidadeDados = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < jsonProdutos.length; i++){
    html +='<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">';
    html +='    <div class="body-card card-links">';
    html +='        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">';
    html +='          <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='               <img src="' + jsonProdutos[i].imagem + '" class="img-fluid">';
    html +='           </div>';
    html +='        </div>';
    html +='            <p>' + jsonProdutos[i].nome + '</p>';
    html +='            <h3  style="color: #005fbb";>' + jsonProdutos[i].preco + '<h3>'; 
  **html +='            <p><a href="?id=produtos&jsonProdutos=JSON.stringify(jsonProdutos[i])" class="btn btn-default" role="button";> Ver Produto </a></p>';**            
    html +='    </div>';
    html +='</div>';
  }
  $('#bodyIndicacao').html(html);
}
```

Comment: You are adding the code as a string and not its actual result. Just concat it like all the other properties in your example. `"?id=produtos&jsonProdutos="' + JSON.stringify(jsonProdutos[i]) + '"`

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know if the problem is in the url var

Comment: What does `console.log(ponto)` show?

Comment: Passing the whole json in the url is not ideal. URL are limited, public and encoded.

Comment: It is not pulling anything on the console

Comment: Is there another form?

Comment: @Mirella Silveira: The provided code alone makes no sense. You have unused declarations like `ponto` and `quantidadeDados`. There is no definition/source of `jsonProdutos`. Just clean up your code while checking the console and you will find the issue on your own.

Comment: the "ponto" is about the url and "quantidadededados" is part of the loop, if i take out this variable that will not work. Clean code is being difficult for a beginner, thanks, Lain

Comment: Is this still open?

Answer (score 0):

This `JSON.stringify(jsonProdutos[i])` is not getting evaluated its been added as a it is as a string to all the links:

Try this

```js
html +='<p><a href="?id=produtos&jsonProdutos=' + JSON.stringify(jsonProdutos[i]) + '" class="btn btn-default" role="button";> Ver Produto </a></p>';
```

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know if the problem is in the url var

Comment: provide the result of console.log(ponto)

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption of how it should work. The content of your `a[href]` was incorrect due to wrong concating and the missing encoding. See below for a running and commented example:

```js
//REM: Apparently somewhere in your URL, there is a key "jsonProdutos" containing json.
var tSampleURL = 'https://www.wayne.com?jsonProdutos=[{"imagem":"image1","nome":"nome1","preco":"preco1"},{"imagem":"image2","nome":"nome2","preco":"preco2"}]';

function listar(url){
  //REM: Removed since I do not have your URL
  //var url_string = window.location.href;
  //var url = new URL(url_string);

  //REM: Not sure what this is for. Probably jsonProdutos
  //var ponto = url.searchParams.get("jsonProdutos");
  //console.log(ponto)

  //REM: The value of "jsonProdutos" from the URL
  var jsonString = new URL(url || window.location.href).searchParams.get('jsonProdutos');

  //REM: The actual values of "jsonProdutos";
  var jsonProdutos = [];
  if(jsonString){
    //REM: Parsing the querystring value into an object
    jsonProdutos = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  };
    
  //REM: Template of the HTML
  var tTemplate = '';
  tTemplate +='<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">';
  tTemplate +='    <div class="body-card card-links">';
  tTemplate +='        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">';
  tTemplate +='          <div class="col-md-12">';
  tTemplate +='               <img src="@imagem." class="img-fluid">';
  tTemplate +='           </div>';
  tTemplate +='        </div>';
  tTemplate +='            <p>@nome.</p>';
  tTemplate +='            <h3 style="color: #005fbb";>@preco.<h3>'; 
  tTemplate +='            <p><a href="?id=produtos&jsonProdutos=@json." class="btn btn-default" role="button"; onclick="return _test(this)"> Ver Produto </a></p>';            
  tTemplate +='    </div>';
  tTemplate +='</div>';
    
  //REM: If there are any entries in jsonProdutos
  if(jsonProdutos && jsonProdutos.length){
    //REM: The HTML that gets added into $('#bodyIndicacao')
    var html = '';

    //REM: Does not get used anywhere
    //var quantidadeDados = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonProdutos.length; i++){
      //REM: Adding the replaced template to the html
      html += tTemplate
        .replace(/@imagem./g, jsonProdutos[i].imagem)
        .replace(/@nome./g, jsonProdutos[i].nome)
        .replace(/@preco./g, jsonProdutos[i].preco)
        //REM: stringifying and encoding the object to JSON
        .replace(/@json./g, encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonProdutos[i])))
    };

    //REM: Adding the html
    $('#bodyIndicacao').html(html)
  }
};

//REM: Test function
function _test(a){
  alert(
    'URL: ' + decodeURI(a.href) + '\n\n' +
    'jsonProdutos: ' + new URL(a.href).searchParams.get('jsonProdutos')
  );
  
  return false
};

//REM: Starting the process
listar(tSampleURL);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'bodyIndicacao'></div>
```